# set radio element text with jQuery supporting IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to set text of the radio element with jQuery supporting IE.
I use this:

```
$('<input>'+variable+'</input>').attr({ 
type: 'radio',
name: 'RadioName',  
value: 'Value'}).appendTo("#Something");
```

Firefox and Chrome support it.
IE doesn't. The error message: "This command is not supported"
I tried .text() and also not supported.

Someone knows another way to set the text of radio.?

Comment: Um... what *Version* of IE are we talking about here?

Comment: It's Internet Explorer 8

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `<input />` and not `<input></input>`...

And to set the text you may use the `<label>` tag

Example working on IE: http://jsfiddle.net/YBVns/3/

```
var variable = "Hello";

$('<input>').attr({ 
type: 'radio',
name: 'RadioName',  
value: 'Value'}).appendTo("body");

$("<label>").text(variable).appendTo("body");
```

Comment: I see, but I'm just trying to set the radio button text.